# Reading an old XP Drive on a Windows 7 unit

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive, sata

I have my mom's old PC and I cannot get her old HD to show up when I connect my SATA read cables up to her hard drive externally. I am wondering if her HD died over night or if I am missing something. I have connect my PC to hers via patch cable, eSATA to the HD, and tried a bridge USB cable to access the HD but no luck. Any advice?

Comment: More information would be nice - Where is it not showing up? Try checking in the disk management console.

Comment: does the drive spin up when it gets power?

Comment: You write "tried a bridge USB cable" what is that?  Have u tried a USB-SATA adaptor? worth trying

Comment: Sorry, its sounds like the hard drive has died.  Does it spin up when power is applied (ie can you hear it making a spinning noise ?).

Also (forgive me, it may be obvious to you) - SATA drives require 2 cables - a small cable for the data + a larger cable to power the drive.  Can you confirm you are plugging in *both* cables ?   Also, does the drive show up at all in the BIOS when its plugged in ?

Answer (score 0):

If both PCs have SATA drives just remove your drive from your PC and add your mums as the boot drive. 
Keep the side off of your PC and as mentioned above check the drive is spinning by putting your hand on it. Some drives are very quiet but you will feel it spin.